# Clustering dense data points horizontally

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have a set of about 34,000 data labels with their respective features (state probabilities) in a 2D numpy array that, visualised as a scatter plot, looks [image: like this].

It's easy to see that the majority of b data points is at the bottom and quite dense. I would like to use a clustering algorithm to extract the bottom area. I don't strive for a perfect result. This is simply about extracting the majority of b points.

So far I have tried the DBSCAN algorithm:

```
import sklearn.cluster as sklc

data1, data2 = zip(*dist_list[1])
data = np.array([data1, data2]).T

core_samples, labels_db = sklc.dbscan(
    data,  # array has to be (n_samples, n_features)
    eps=2.0,
    min_samples=5,
    metric='euclidean',
    algorithm='auto'
)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(labels_db, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[core_samples] = True

unique_labels = set(labels_db)

n_clusters_ = len(unique_labels) - (1 if -1 in labels_db else 0)

colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels)))
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = 'k'

    class_member_mask = (labels_db == k)

    xy = data[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col, markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

    xy = data[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'x', markerfacecolor=col, markeredgecolor='k', markersize=4)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15, 15)
plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

which yields [image: this plot].

Increasing the minimal amount of samples simply results in smaller vertical lines being classified as noise and the longer (and denser) vertical lines staying.

I also tried clustering with `scipy.cluster.hierarchy`:

```
thresh = 2
clusters = hcluster.fclusterdata(data, thresh, criterion="distance")

plt.scatter(*data.T, c=clusters)
title = "t=%f, n=%d" % (thresh, len(set(clusters)))
plt.title(title)
plt.show()
```

which resulted in a similar vertical classification. Please view the comment for the plot. With my reputation I'm not allowed to post more than two links yet.

Now my question is, did I make a mistake in the calibration of the algorithms? Or was my choice of algorithms wrong in the first place? How can I extract the dense area of b data points?

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i1wp7.png) is the similar classification I ended up with after using the scipy hierarchy algorithm.

Comment: Try to scale your data. The x-axis ranges from 0 to 35,000 while the y-axis from 0 to 1. The vertical distances are much smaller than the horizontal ones, that's why the algorithms cluster the datapoints vertically. Check out the preprocessing utilities of Scikit-learn (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html).

Comment: Perhaps you're overthinking this. It looks as though you could do very well just by applying a threshold to your y-values, e.g. median +/- 0.01.

Comment: What about a 1-dimensional (linear) array, e.g. a timeline with events (or lack thereof)?  How can we find the denseness, clustering for highest density without pre-specifying (1 point is infinite density, and 2 close points are very high, but perhaps there's a cluster of 5 or 15 points that come close to a high density)?  Is that a simple procedure, or must it be done iteratively?  In SAS (my language of choice), one can use lag code to find average for n points  [link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/69762/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0l66p5oqex1f2n1quuopdvtcjqb.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1. Never include ID attributes. Your "node index" supposedly should not be used for similarity computations, should it?
2. When your **attributes have different units and scale** you need to be very careful. A popular heuristic is `StandardScaler`, i.e. normalize each attribute to have unit variance. But given the distribution of your data (uniform on x, skewed on y) I do not think the use of standardization is well supported by theory - it assumes Gaussian distributions.

The combination of these two is why you get this result: your x axis completely dominates the result. It literally has over 10000x the influence than your y axis  You are effectively clustering only based on Node ID...

**Never assume clustering "just works"**. All of these methods are *very* sensitive to preprocessing, and therefor need to be applied with care.